# Pageable with native query

Tags: javascript, sql, spring-boot, jpa, nativequery

I have this query, when I try to execute it, appear the syntax error refer to 'WHERE'. How can I make it run?

```
@Query(value = "SELECT PERSONA, APELLIDOMATERNO, APELLIDOPATERNO, NOMBRES, NOMBRECOMPLETO, TIPODOCUMENTO,\r\n"
 + "DOCUMENTO, FECHANACIMIENTO, SEXO, DIRECCION, TELEFONO, DOCUMENTOFISCAL, CORREOELECTRONICO,\r\n"
 + "ESTADO, CELULAR, CASE WHEN ESEMPRESA IS NULL THEN 'NO' WHEN ESEMPRESA = 'Y' THEN 'SI' ELSE 'NO' END AS 'esempresa'\r\n"
 + "FROM Prospecto\r\n"
 + "WHERE (:p_documento is null or :p_documento = '' or DOCUMENTO = :p_documento)\r\n"
 + "AND (:p_nombre is null or :p_nombre = '' or UPPER(NOMBRECOMPLETO) like '%'
 + UPPER(:p_nombre) + '%')\r\n" + "AND (:p_empresa is null or :p_empresa = '' or UPPER(ESEMPRESA) like '%'
 + UPPER(With the method:p_empresa)
 + '%')\r\n"
 + "AND p.ESTADO = 'A'\r\n" + "ORDER BY 1 DESC", nativeQuery = true) Page getPersonasActive(@Param("p_documento") String documento, @Param("p_nombre") String nombre, @Param("p_empresa") String empresa, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Please clean up the formatting of your question. Also only add tags that are relevant to the question. Where is the javascript in this question?

Comment: is `UPPER(With the method:p_empresa)` correct syntax?.  Is using single quotes around column aliases correct syntax as in `...AS 'esempresa'? What rdbms platform is this?